# Check when DataTables finished rendering

Tags: jquery, .net-core, datatables

I'm rendering a lot of data to a table with razor in .Net Core. I'm using DataTables on the table, and trying to add a spinner/loading text while it's loading/rendering the data in the table.

I've tried the `initComplete` callback, but that fires earlier (at least what I can see in the browser and console.log, it logs a few seconds before it's complete). So is it possible to somehow check if the DataTable completed the render?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`initComplete` triggers once datatable is initialised. You can use `draw` delegate instead.
Have a look at below example

```
var table = $('#tableId').DataTable();

table.on( 'draw', function () {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Ended up using the drawCallback (which is the same as you mentioned) for hiding/showing the table and a loading spinner. Thanks.

Comment: Great. But using .on("draw") delegate has one additional benefit, it will also work on dynamically loaded content in future.